# Lost focus in TextFormField

Tags: flutter

I have problema when i delete all the info in my TexFormField. He seems to be losing focus. I have tried several methods but I don´t see that it works

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is9X1.gif)

```
 
    return FocusScope(
      node: FocusScopeNode(),
      autofocus: false,
      canRequestFocus: true,
      child: TextFormField(
        focusNode: focusNode,
        textCapitalization: textCapitalization,
        onTapOutside: (event) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
        onChanged: (value) {
          onChanged?.call(value);
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            focusNode?.requestFocus();
          }
        },
        
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
return Form(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Consumer(
            builder: (context, watch, _) {
              final cedulaController =
                  MaskedTextController(mask: '000-0000000-0');

              cedulaController.text = formValue.cedula.value;

              return CustomTextFormField(

                readOnly: false,
                label: 'Digite su número de cédula',
                controller: cedulaController,
                onChanged: (cedula) async {
                  
                 ...........................................................
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 FocusScope(
        node: FocusScopeNode(),
        autofocus: false,
        canRequestFocus: true,
        child: TextFormField(
          focusNode: focusNode,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
          textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
          onTapOutside: (event) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
          onChanged: (value) {
            onChanged?.call(value);
            if (value.isEmpty) {
              focusNode?.requestFocus();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
```